# How are SignalR groups implemented without state on server?

Tags: signalr

This [page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) in the SignalR docs states:

> SignalR sends messages to clients and groups based on a pub/sub model, and the server does not maintain lists of groups or group memberships. This helps maximize scalability, because whenever you add a node to a web farm, any state that SignalR maintains has to be propagated to the new node.

The mentioned scalability benefit of implementing the groups without maintaining state on the server is clear, but how does it work?

Presumably if you send a message to a group, the server must have a list of the connections in each group in order to be able to look them up and send the message to each one.  But this says no such list is maintained.  Even the statement that it is "based on a pub/sub model" is confusing, since a pub/sub system itself needs to maintain a list of the subscribers in order to know who to publish to.

Does anyone know how this works in SignalR?